# I'm failing to create a pagedown::chrome_print pdf output from a shiny app which takes parameter inputs and renders the Rmarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, pagedown

I have a rmarkdown file which is built around the {pagedreport} package (an add-on to pagedown). This creates a html and them uses pagedown::chrome_print to convert the html to pdf.

The rmarkdown file i have works as planned when I have the parameters manually entered on the rmarkdown file, but I want to be able to pick my parameters from a shiny app.

I currently have tried this approach

```
    output$report <- downloadHandler(
    # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
    filename =  "new_report.pdf",
    content = function(file) {
    # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
    # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
    # can happen when deployed).
    tempReport <- file.path("../temp/", "myRmarkdown.Rmd")
    file.copy("myRmarkdown.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
    
    # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
    params <- list(A = input$A, B = input$B)
    
    # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
    # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
    # from the code in this app).
                  
                     
     library(rmarkdown)
     render(tempReport,  params = params,
                   envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))

            
          }
```

and I get the result:

```
    Output created: MyRmarkdown.html
```

but there is no pdf created. Pagedown uses chrome_print to convert - and this is in the yaml of the Rmarkdown.

This is the YAML of my Rmarkdown file

```
    output:
    pagedreport::paged_windmill:
    img_to_dark: TRUE
    logo_to_white: TRUE
    knit: pagedown::chrome_print
    #toc: TRUE
    toc-title: "Table of Contents"
    #toc_depth: 1
    main-color: "#264653"
    secondary-color: "#2a9d8f"
    google-font: TRUE
    main-font: "Raleway" 
    header-font: "Roboto"
    params:
        A: NA
        B: NA
    editor_options: 
    markdown: 
        wrap: 72
```

I know there is an issue between shiny and chrome_print() where you need to add chrome_print(..., async = TRUE), but I don't know where to put this argument in my shiny app?

Comment: I have written a demo Shiny app to show how to use `pagedown::chrome_print()` in Shiny, see https://github.com/RLesur/chrome_print_shiny.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you have to make sure that your `render` function creates a file at the location given by the argument `file`. In  your current appraoch `render` uses defaults, which won't work. Thus, it should be as simple as adding the `output_file` argument to `render`. The following code snippets works for me:

### `test.Rmd`

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
params:
   title: "Test"
   heading: "Header"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r results="asis"}
cat("## ", params$title)
```

You passed in argument `r cat(params$heading)`
````

### `app.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)

ui <- fluidPage(textInput("heading", "Heading"), 
                textInput("title", "Title"), 
                downloadButton("download_ok", "Works"),
                downloadButton("download_nok", "Does not Work"))

server <- function(input, output) {
   output$download_ok <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
         paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".html", sep="")
      },
      content = function(file) {
         p <- list(title = input$title,
                        heading = input$heading)
         render("test.Rmd", output_file = file, params = p)
      }
   )
   
   output$download_nok <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
         paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".html", sep="")
      },
      content = function(file) {
         p <- list(title = input$title,
                        heading = input$heading)
         render("test.Rmd", params = p)
      }
   )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This snippet shows how this works now in principle, I do not know `pagedreport`. If there is an option in the YAML to produce `pdfs` right away (without the manual call to whatever function) this should work in the same way.

If you absolutely need to call the function, you can do that in the `downloadHandler` after the `render` assuming that the function can deal with input file names and create output files at the given location (again you need to create the file at the given location [as per argument `file`])

---

After reading the docs of `pagedown::chrome_print` you can adapt your `downloadHandler` as follows:

```
output$report <- downloadHandler(
      filename =  "new_report.pdf",
      content = function(file) {
         tempReport <- file.path("../temp/", "myRmarkdown.Rmd")
         file.copy("myRmarkdown.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
         params <- list(A = input$A, B = input$B)
         html_fn <- rmarkdown::render(tempReport,  params = params,
                envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
         
         pagedown::chrome_print(html_fn, file)
      }
```